# Dynamically select columns of a master dataframe - paste and export output to new seperate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am working on a project which is updated every few years. We then get new data for every quarter. Usually a table, in which columns 1:5 are IDs and discriptive information necessary for further analysis. And then there are consecutive pairs of columns (e.g. 6:7, 8:9, ...) which contain the updated data (variables) for the specific quarter. So far so good.

The problem is that given the unregular update interval, the input data is quite different. Sometimes I get CSVs for one quarter, sometimes for a number of quarters, and sometimes the date is even in SPSS format (sav). I managed to automatically join all past and current files, when I have the input data in the following format: columns 1:5 descriptive data, columns 6:7 updated data.

So what's left to do is to import data from CSVs or SAVs that cointain more than one quarter, split them into seperate dataframes in the requested format (columns 1:5 descriptive data, columns 6:7 new variables), and export the new dataframe as CSV to a specific location - if possible even automatically naming them.

While this is fairly easy to do manually, I could not come up with an automated solution, as there are so many variable factors. Manually I would use the dplyr package:

```
tops_2007_1 <- tops_2007_1_2015_2 %>% select(1:5, 6:7) #and so forth
tops_2007_2 <- tops_2007_1_2015_2 %>% select(1:5, 8:9)
...


write_excel_csv2(tops_2007_1, "Data/Tops/tops_2007_1.csv") # and so forth
write_excel_csv2(tops_2007_2, "Data/Tops/tops_2007_2.csv")
...
```

Is there a way to automate this? Information on the new dataframe names would be in the column headers (e.g. 20071_X, 20071_Y). I got plenty of hints towards for loops and apply functions, but failed to put it together. I would appreciate any hints that could get me started on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same random data generated by @Limey, you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

Generate some random data
df <- tibble(
        id1=rnorm(10),id2=rnorm(10),id3=rnorm(10),id4=rnorm(10),id5=rnorm(10),
        var1x=rnorm(10),var1y=rnorm(10),var2x=rnorm(10),var2y=rnorm(10),var3x=rnorm(10),
        var3y=rnorm(10),var4x=rnorm(10),var4y=rnorm(10),var5x=rnorm(10),var5y=rnorm(10)
)

spits <- split(names(df)[6:length(names(df))], ceiling(seq_along(names(df)[6:length(names(df))])/2))

pmap(list(spits,1:length(spits)), ~df%>%select(1:5,all_of(..1))%>%write_excel_csv2(.,paste0('tops_2007_',as.character(..2),'.csv')))
```

Which outputs:

```
$`1`
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      id1    id2     id3    id4    id5   var1x  var1y
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.748  0.587  1.47    2.23  -1.06   0.618   0.642
 2 -1.07  -1.29   1.03    0.222 -0.266 -0.824   0.862
 3  0.872 -1.62   0.225   1.31  -0.737  0.885  -0.569
 4 -1.85   0.653  0.279  -1.28  -1.04   0.0762  0.769
 5  0.913 -2.27   0.0821  1.10   1.04   1.50    0.791
 6  1.36   0.203 -0.310   1.43   1.43  -0.489   0.259
 7 -0.961  1.10   0.642  -1.42   2.01  -1.79   -0.732
 8  0.861 -0.831  1.29    0.684 -0.124  0.0549  0.755
 9  1.20   1.43   1.20   -0.287 -1.35  -1.48    0.237
10 -0.645  1.01   0.411   0.383 -0.413  1.75    0.386

$`2`
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      id1    id2     id3    id4    id5   var2x  var2y
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.748  0.587  1.47    2.23  -1.06  -0.602  -0.938
 2 -1.07  -1.29   1.03    0.222 -0.266  1.47    0.122
 3  0.872 -1.62   0.225   1.31  -0.737 -0.600   0.584
 4 -1.85   0.653  0.279  -1.28  -1.04  -0.835  -0.918
 5  0.913 -2.27   0.0821  1.10   1.04  -0.322   0.623
 6  1.36   0.203 -0.310   1.43   1.43   0.333   1.22 
 7 -0.961  1.10   0.642  -1.42   2.01  -0.287  -0.471
 8  0.861 -0.831  1.29    0.684 -0.124  0.0853 -1.34 
 9  1.20   1.43   1.20   -0.287 -1.35   0.800  -0.528
10 -0.645  1.01   0.411   0.383 -0.413  0.982   1.76 

$`3`
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      id1    id2     id3    id4    id5    var3x  var3y
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.748  0.587  1.47    2.23  -1.06  -0.00896  0.320
 2 -1.07  -1.29   1.03    0.222 -0.266 -0.321    0.213
 3  0.872 -1.62   0.225   1.31  -0.737  0.785    1.81 
 4 -1.85   0.653  0.279  -1.28  -1.04   0.965    0.695
 5  0.913 -2.27   0.0821  1.10   1.04   1.18     1.22 
 6  1.36   0.203 -0.310   1.43   1.43  -1.64     0.804
 7 -0.961  1.10   0.642  -1.42   2.01   0.648    1.25 
 8  0.861 -0.831  1.29    0.684 -0.124 -0.933   -0.483
 9  1.20   1.43   1.20   -0.287 -1.35   1.56     0.710
10 -0.645  1.01   0.411   0.383 -0.413 -2.24     0.964

$`4`
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      id1    id2     id3    id4    id5   var4x   var4y
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.748  0.587  1.47    2.23  -1.06   0.172  -0.901 
 2 -1.07  -1.29   1.03    0.222 -0.266 -0.336  -0.720 
 3  0.872 -1.62   0.225   1.31  -0.737  2.18   -0.557 
 4 -1.85   0.653  0.279  -1.28  -1.04   1.18    1.30  
 5  0.913 -2.27   0.0821  1.10   1.04   0.0288  0.369 
 6  1.36   0.203 -0.310   1.43   1.43  -1.34    0.506 
 7 -0.961  1.10   0.642  -1.42   2.01   0.193   0.0254
 8  0.861 -0.831  1.29    0.684 -0.124  0.209   0.168 
 9  1.20   1.43   1.20   -0.287 -1.35   0.181   0.658 
10 -0.645  1.01   0.411   0.383 -0.413  1.40   -0.360 

$`5`
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      id1    id2     id3    id4    id5    var5x  var5y
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.748  0.587  1.47    2.23  -1.06   0.0203   1.14 
 2 -1.07  -1.29   1.03    0.222 -0.266 -1.22     0.339
 3  0.872 -1.62   0.225   1.31  -0.737 -0.423   -0.291
 4 -1.85   0.653  0.279  -1.28  -1.04   0.815   -0.428
 5  0.913 -2.27   0.0821  1.10   1.04  -0.00963 -0.690
 6  1.36   0.203 -0.310   1.43   1.43   0.141    0.451
 7 -0.961  1.10   0.642  -1.42   2.01  -1.77     1.60 
 8  0.861 -0.831  1.29    0.684 -0.124  0.370    0.438
 9  1.20   1.43   1.20   -0.287 -1.35  -0.582   -2.92 
10 -0.645  1.01   0.411   0.383 -0.413  1.33    -0.221
```

and creates the following files in your directory:

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm - although it's quite beyond my skillset. I will need some time to figure out what's happening under the hood. :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works. The major thing here is the `pmap` function from the `purrr` package. It's a great package if you can learn how to use it. It has functions like `map` and several other variants that you can use for easy looping. You can accept the answer for others who may have a similar question.

Comment: `pmap` looks really interesting - I will definetly have a look at the `map` family. Thanks as well for pointing out the "accepted answer"-feature.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

Generate some random data
df <- tibble(
        id1=rnorm(10),id2=rnorm(10),id3=rnorm(10),id4=rnorm(10),id5=rnorm(10),
        var1x=rnorm(10),var1y=rnorm(10),var2x=rnorm(10),var2y=rnorm(10),var3x=rnorm(10),
        var3y=rnorm(10),var4x=rnorm(10),var4y=rnorm(10),var5x=rnorm(10),var5y=rnorm(10)
)

ans <- bind_rows(
         lapply(
           seq(6, ncol(df), 2),
           function(x) {
             df %>% 
               select(1:5, c(x, x+1)) %>% 
               rename(x=6, y=7) %>% 
               add_column(var=floor((x-5)/2)+1)
           }
         )
       )
ans
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 50 x 8
       id1     id2     id3    id4     id5      x      y   var
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.816   0.315  -0.0932  0.232 -0.950  -1.17  -0.157     1
 2 -0.0704  1.15    1.67    2.85  -2.61   -0.190 -1.60      1
 3 -1.94   -0.343   0.873  -1.13  -0.638   0.802 -0.254     1
 4 -1.19    0.247   0.0939  0.337  1.99   -0.806  1.43      1
 5  0.100  -1.61   -1.39   -0.253 -1.53   -1.99  -1.04      1
 6 -0.106  -0.244  -0.233   2.49   1.60    0.229  0.919     1
 7 -0.979  -0.648   0.432   1.22  -1.16   -0.754  0.903     1
 8  0.284  -0.220  -0.735  -0.804  0.0707 -0.714 -1.87      1
 9 -0.0801 -1.53   -0.819   0.952  0.852   1.27  -0.702     1
10 -0.579  -0.0120  0.611  -0.621 -2.13   -0.812  1.43      1
# … with 40 more rows
```

How does it work?

```
seq(6, ncol(df), 2)
```

Defines the first of each pair of columns you wish to extract, starting with the 6th (the first after your first 5 `id` variables) and stepping through the columns in steps of two.

```
             df %>% 
               select(1:5, c(x, x+1))
```

Selects the id columns and the current pair of data columns

```
               rename(x=6, y=7) %>% 
               add_column(var=floor((x-5)/2)+1)
```

Renames the two data columns to `x` and `y` and adds a new id column identifying which pair of data columns are being handled.  You will need to adapt this step to reflect your actual data.

```
lapply(...)
```

Performs the above steps on all pairs of data columns in the current data frame and returns the results as a list

```
bind_rows(...)
```

Converts the list of data frames to a single one.

Some comments:

- Using column indexes to identify columns is fragile.  I wouldn't do it.  I'd use the column names themselves.
- If your data column names are, for example, `20071_X` then your data are not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) because the column names contain information (here, the year and the quarter).  This will likely cause you pain downstream.  I'd recommend putting this right as soon as you can.  By modifying my derivation of `var`, you can tidy your data as you extract it.
- Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for advice on how to write a good minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the detailed walk through - that made it easy to follow. Thanks also for the suggestions on identifying and labelling columns. The labelling is predefined by another department - I will suggest something else based on your input. :)